# Why must one recite any scripture while donning Rabbe'inu Tam tephillin?

Tags: halacha, tefilin, shulchan-aruch, mishnah-berurah

The Mishnah Berurah ([Oraḥ Ḥayim 25:4, s.q. 14](http://www.mishnaberurayomi.org/pdf_pages/Chelek_1/0058_Siman_25_Seif_1b-5a.pdf)) clarifies that the reason one must be careful while reciting Shema' Yisra'el (and the 'Amidah) to also don tephillin is **so as not to appear as a false witness** (since Shema' Yisra'el mentions wearing tephillin and one who recites it without tephillin appears to be saying one thing and doing another).

The Mishnah Berurah ([Oraḥ Ḥayim 34:2, s.q. 15](http://www.mishnaberurayomi.org/pdf_pages/Chelek_1/0112_Siman_34_Seif_2c-4a.pdf)) cites this same reasoning to explain why one must also recite (the first two paragraphs) of **Shema' Yisra'el while donning Rabbe'inu Tam tephillin.**

I'm having difficulty understanding the Mishnah Berurah's logic in Siman 34. The concern about donning (any) tephillin while reciting Shema' Yisra'el is that in doing so one appears to be a false witness. But, that's only true when one is required to recite Shema'. In the case of Rabbe'inu Tam tephillin being donned *after* one already recited Shema' Yisra'el (and the 'Amidah) while donning RaSh"I tephillin, why one must one recite *anything*?

**In summary**, my understanding of the Mishnah Berurah in Siman 25 is "*if Shema' then tephillin*" whereas in Siman 34 **it appears that the logic is reversed** (i.e. "*if tephillin then Shema'*"). Can someone please help me explain what appears IMHO to be reverse logic?

Comment: Where is the link for this mishna berura online, not in hebrewbooks, is it free?

Comment: @kouty It's from mishnaberurayomi.org

Answer (score 5):

The logic is that if one said Shema with Rashi's, but Rabbeinu Tam's is the correct Tefillin, then one didn't say Shema with Tefillin earlier, so say it now, properly. So the logic is that the proper way to say Shema is with Tefillin on, so if you failed to do it before, do it now. That is what the Mishna Brura is saying that he "fixed" his failure to say Shema with Tefillin by saying the first two paragraphs.

[Kitzur Yalkut Yosef](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_3.html#HtmpReportNum0010_L2) (25:40) says in part:

> ואין בזה משום כל הקורא קריאת שמע בלי תפילין כאילו מעיד עדות שקר בעצמו, אחר שבדעתו להניח תפילין אחר כך. ובלבד שיהיה בדעתו לקרוא שוב לאחר זמן קריאת שמע עם התפילין
>
> ...
>
> וגם מניח תפילין אחר כך בו ביום, אין בזה משום מעיד עדות שקר בעצמו. מאחר שבדעתו לומר קריאת שמע אחר כך עם תפילין

The context there is someone who is late and doesn't have time to put on Tefillin before the end of the time to say Shema. He says by saying Shema before the end of the time without Tefillin and having in mind to **re-say Shema** afterwards with Tefillin avoids the "false testimony" issue.

It is quite possible that this the mechanics that the Mishna Brura (et. al.) have in mind here.

Comment: Didn't he already fulfill the Mitzva? What Mitzva is he fulfilling now by saying those verses? I don't get how saying true testimony later solves having said false testimony earlier.

Comment: @DoubleAA My understanding of Yishai's answer is that, while not solving the earlier (possible) "false testimony", one is at least ensuring "true testimony" each day by reciting Shema' with each set of tephillin. It's like a hedge.

Comment: @Lee Seems more like you'd be guaranteeing that you would deliver some false testimony. Indeed, how is saying Shema with RT Tefillin permitted at all? I understand why you have to say it once and so we are forced to pick a set of Tefillin to wear then. But how can you justify saying it again (especially given that the "main Halakha" is against RT)? Since when is there an obligation to say one true testimony about Tefillin each day?

Comment: @Lee I also don't know how you are ensuring a true testimony. The Mitzva of Shema is over. Everything else is just saying random verses with no Halakhic import and no one TTBOMK thinks reading verses about Tefillin without Tefillin on is a problem of false testimony (can I not practice Leining Bo/Vaetchanan/Ekev without Tefillin on???). Unless the principle is to say Shema Al Tenai? That would be an interesting position valuing Keriat Shema with Tefillin over (the first two paragraphs of) Keriat Shema with its Berakhot.

Comment: @DoubleAA Now I understand your objection to Yishai's proposal. The second recitation of Shema' is simply a recitation of Torah verses and not the fulfillment of a Mizwah (and therefore bears no impact on the prior "false testimony"). So, what does one accomplish by reciting them? Great elucidation of your objection - thanks.

Comment: Yishai, FWIW I don't think you'll find answers, and the key is that this suggestion is for someone who לבו נוקפו. It's just a sort of 'extra' for someone who is overly concerned. It's not a strict Halakhic thing. If you find anything different please let me know.

Comment: @Yishai This is not the way it is explained according to the Rebbe, Rabbi Menachem Azariah of Fano or the Remak in Pardes Rimonim. Each of the four pairs of tefillin is for the particular tzeruf of G-d's name. When the tzeruf changes, a different recital of Shema is required.

Comment: @YaacovDeane: That sounds like an answer. Do you have more specific sources (e.g. chapter numbers, name of sefarim, etc?)

Comment: @YaacovDeane Only one recital of Shema is ever required, according to Halakha, no matter what sorts of clothes/adornments you are wearing.

Comment: @DoubleAA That's correct. It is one of the reasons why the custom of some is to put multiple pairs of tefillin on at the same time.

Comment: @YaacovDeane But, one could never don four pairs simultaneously. So, we're still left with DoubleAA's question of what is achieved by the subsequent recitation(s) of Shema'.

Comment: @Lee You may find vol. 1 of Sefer Divrei Shalom, siman 25 on the laws of tefillin interesting. It mentions several sources saying Moshe Rabbeinu put on two pair and Eliyahu appears to have worn at least three. The suggestion there is that Rashi and Rabbeinu Tam are obligatory.

Comment: For those who don't learn the kavannot, the recital would at least be learning Torah. But to fulfill mitzvot properly, kavannot are required. That includes according to Halacha. It's important to keep in mind that generally, books of halacha outline minimum and/or maximum boundaries of observance.

Comment: @YaacovDeane What does learning Torah have to do with anything? Once the Mitzva or Saying Shema is done, whether you properly hacked it with Kabbalistic nuance or not, it's done. I don't see how you are responding to Lee.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Then Sefer Divrei Shalom is making the problem even worse! According to your explanation of those sources, one following the opinion of the Sh"'A (Oraḥ Ḥayim 34:2) bears false testimony twice since during neither Shema' recitation is he properly donning tephillin!

Comment: See also Aruch HaShulchan 25:8. He's bringing same idea. It's not a problem and is even by minimum considered a good thing.

Comment: @Lee What you are saying about 'false testimony' is wrong and is not even implied in my comments to Yishai's answer. How he was attempting to explain the concept of multiple pairs of tefillin is incorrect. The sources I mentioned including Shaalot v'Teshuvot HaRema miFano, siman 107 give the concept correctly. Before discounting them, trying learning them.

Comment: @YaacovDeane, that is the Kabbalistic reason. The reason in Poskim (including that very Siman (34:2) of Shulchan Aruch) is as outlined in my answer.

Comment: @DoubleAA, ליבו נקפו is the reason brought in Shulchan Aruch HaRav, yes. However you answer the Mishna Brura (and the Pri Megadim that he quotes and the Maharil 137 - who uses the word ידאג), what is stated in my answer is his reasoning - which was the OP question.

Comment: @Yishai לבו נקפו is in the Levush first IINM. IAE while you roughly identify what the MB literally said, a fuller answer would outline the mechanics of it (Shema al Tenai, etc.) and presenting this alone as if it's actually a logical Halakhic argument is just bound to further confuse the OP. (But I would never dream of downvoting this.)

Comment: @DoubleAA, Shma Al Tenai is a big chiddush with several nafka minas. Its certainly a nicely wrapped up Halachic bundle, but it would require finishing Davening and putting on RT before Sof Zman KS, not to mention the actual failure to mention the need to have the condition, etc. However, Kitzur Yalkut Yosef (25:40) just says that if you say Krias Shema without Tefillin with the intention of *saying it again* with Tefillin, that avoids the Edus Sheker issue. That would be a simpler answer for here.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Thank you for the reference. In 107, Rama' says nothing of what you said, but instead recommends saying an extra Shema with the 'non-standard' Tefillin _before_ Shacharit due to doubt, and wearing the 'standard' Tefillin for Shacharit (which is the opposite of the ShA's reference). While he doesn't mention Eidut Sheker (or skipping the third paragraph) at all, this certainly opens up discussion into new value of the second Shema as being part of the Berakhot (a la Rav Hai Gaon in OC 60).

Comment: @Yishai It would be a simpler answer. Would it explain skipping the third paragraph? Does he have classical support for it? (Even better) is that classical support Lishitateih (ie also from Maharil or the Ashkenazi school in general), or does at least MB not explicitly disagree? Does it need to be done before Sof Zman KS? I didn't mean to say Tenai is the only possibility, just that to really round out this answer I feel you need more explanation.

Comment: @DoubleAA, It probably would explain it, as the need to repeat it is the need to repeat the relevant testimonial verses. He does say in 34:2 to only say the first two chapters with Rabbeinu Tam, although he doesn't restate this reason, or give any other reason. I would have to check in the Yalkut Yosef itself for your other questions, which unfortunately I don't have access to now.

Comment: @DoubleAA, in terms of the Mishna Brura's opinion, interestingly in Siman 66 he just quotes the Magein Avraham verbatim to say some tehillim in Rashi Tefillin if he didn't have it when he said Shema, without mentioning saying the first two paragraphs of Shema again then. That is an inherit contradiction, whatever the reason. Perhaps it is a bit of support for the Al Tenai argument, that he actually expected you to put on Rabbeinu Tam before SZKS. Or perhaps he just didn't want to add his own Chiddush here, and would prefer to rely on the language of previous poskim.

Comment: @Yishai See too the Beiur Halakha 66 V'Eilu, the second half. I think that further supports my original contention that there is no mechanic, at least in the Mishna Berura.

Comment: http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01528_part_11.html

Comment: @DoubleAA, that article quotes the Eshel Avraham as stating the requirement to say the first two paragraphs of Shema with Tefillin on sometime during the day to avoid the Eidus Sheker issue. Definitely an Ashkenazi source.

Comment: @Yishai The original source is a Teshuva of Maharil! Certainly it's Ashkenazim who came up with this. Our only question is in what way is it accomplishing anything, if it's accomplishing anything substantive at all.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I mean the idea that saying it again during the day helps the Eidus Sheker issue. שדוקא אם עבר כל היום ולא אמר ק"ש בהיות תפילין עליו אז הו"ל כעדות שקר. It is an Ashkenazi source for the Yalkut Yosef.

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7805&st=&pgnum=97&hilite= in passing notes that one who is saying shema earlier because of the zman would obviously put on tefillin then, and then later when saying "fake" shema in davening one wouldn't need to interrupt bein haperakim to don tefillin since he already said shema.