# Why do we recite the Shema when putting on tefillin (whether Rashi or Rabbein Tam) after the time of Shacharis?

Tags: halacha-theory, tefilin

I have read another Q&A, [Why must one recite any scripture while donning Rabbe'inu Tam tephillin?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/73978/why-must-one-recite-any-scripture-while-donning-rabbeinu-tam-tephillin) I don't see how it answers my question.

When I put on Rabbeinu Tam tefillin after Shacharis, I repeat the Shema, as the siddur instructs. I believe that this is also the procedure for someone who initially said Shacharis without tefillin and later put on Rashi tefillin.

I'm not sure I see the logic in this. Is the recital of Shema some part of the mitzvah of wearing tefillin?

I've been told that we repeat the Shema because of the "false witness against ourselves," when we initially recited the Shema and therein recited the commandment to wear tefillin, while not wearing tefillin at all or while not fulfilling Rabbeinu Tam's understanding of the requirements of tefillin.

But this seems wrong. If someone neither recited Shema nor wore tefillin, and then after the time for the Shema he wanted to put on tefillin, would he recite the Shema while wearing the tefillin? If so, this doesn't seem to because of the "false witness" argument. Would we resort to the "false witness" on previous days' or nights' recital of the Shema? What of someone who had never recited the Shema?

And why doesn't the "false witness" analysis require one to recite the Shema while hanging a mezuza?

Or does it?

Comment: I don't follow your `But this seems wrong`. I'd asdume that the instructions in the siddur assume you *have* said shema already, as part of shacharit. Do you have instructions to say shema in any of the cases you are describing in that paragraph?

Comment: @magicker72 The instructions don't go into the question. I agree: they assume a reader who did recite Shacharis with Rashi tefillin. But I'm questioning the proffered reasoning by asking whether it's true that the Shema is associated with afternoon tefillin ONLY if one did in fact recite Shema in the morning.

Comment: Then perhaps you should ask just that question first. You say (in paragraph 2) that "you believe" it's the same procedure, and the rest of the question is based off that assumption, so perhaps ascertain the truth of that assumption first.

Comment: *Kabbalas 'ol malchus shamayim* daily is not complete without t'fillin ([*B'rachos* 15a](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.14b.25?lang=bi), "ויניח תפילין ויקרא ק"ש ויתפלל וזו היא מלכות שמים שלמה").

Comment: I think your questions might be better than any answers you might find. But after all none of these things are strictly required, as opposed to being "good" symbolic actions, so you may be expecting too much consistency/logic underneath.

Comment: @Double AA In other words the recital of Shema is always a part of tefillin observance, and never a part of any other mitzvah, regardless of how (or whether) one previously recited the morning Shema; and this explanation about false witness is just a rough fit to this rule.

Comment: I think @DoubleAA was making the opposite point that Shema and tefillin are fundamentally two independent mitzvos that can be fulfilled independently. (However, it is less than ideal to do so because [1] if one recited the morning time Shema without tefillin it is "as if he testified falsely" [the poskim emphasize the "as if" and point out that it is not strictly false testimony], and [2] there is an additional element of *kabbalas 'ol malchus shamayim* [accepting the yoke of Heaven], which is fulfilled in its most complete form when praying and reciting the Shema with tefillin on).